# Error while importing the project into Eclipse workspace

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I have had this problem for a while now. Eclipse shows error when I import the project into Eclipse.

It was showing me many errors before, but I managed to get rid of some. I don't know how to get rid of this errors. [image]

Below is the code for the activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
ListView mDrawerList;
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private CharSequence mTitle;
private String[] mPlanetTitles;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    // opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
    mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
    R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
    R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                        // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(
        com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case android.R.id.home: {
        if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
        break;
    }

    case R.id.action_contact:
        // QuickContactFragment dialog = new QuickContactFragment();
        // dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "QuickContactFragment");
        // return true;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

// The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.content,
                        PageSlidingTabStripFragment.newInstance(),
                        PageSlidingTabStripFragment.TAG).commit();
        break;
    default:

        SherlockFragment fragment = new PlanetFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(PlanetFragment.ARG_PLANET_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.content, fragment).commit();
        break;
    }

    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

}

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Don't post the snapshot. Post your code here with the errors.

Comment: Also have you added Android SDK to your Eclipse?

Comment: yes, I have made working app with Eclipse

Comment: This problem is just with importing any android project. It works perfect when I create separate android project

Comment: Have you tried right click on project and Android tools>Fix project properties ? Sometimes this does the trick. If this doesn't work add files one by one manually in new project. :P I had same problem many times and only making new project worked.

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz, yes I have tried that too.. I wanted permanent solution of this. I knew I could solve it by making new project and adding files each time. But its too much pain to do it every time when you import something

Comment: I know, i had several times huuuuge project and only new project solved it. As far as i know eclipse has overwritten something important...

Comment: What kind of errors are these, unresolvable imports? Do you have the correct API level installed for that application? Have you added the necessary libraries to the project (for ActionBarSherlock)?

Comment: @JustinJasmann, I don't know what kind of errors its called, but yea I have all the libs needed for this project. TargetSDKversion = "17", and I have that downloaded. minSDKversion="8", I dont have min Sdk Downloaded, do you think it might be the problem?

Comment: @DushyantPatel You should only need the SDK that you're building against (target). If you're referencing any classes/methods from third party libraries, those need to be added to the build path as well.

Comment: @DjDexter5GHz, hey man I found the solution. When you create new android application, we have library called "android-support-v4.jar". This "android-support-v4.jar" was missing when I imported this particular project, I just had to import this lib and it worked. Hope it helps you man

Comment: @DushyantPatel check your lib folder(jar files), i think some jar files are missing there

Comment: @Dushyant Patel How the hell did you find that :D. Thanks, next time i will check that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't really hard. I was getting error, because I have having error in my xml files.